# How to pass v-for value outside the loop in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am really struggling on this issue which I first thought would be simple but turns out to be difficult.

I have multiple select dropdowns like this in a bootstrap 4.5 table:

```html
<select class="form-control" @change="selection($event, item.id)" v-bind:style="{ background: '#000' }"
style="width:100px">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option :value="data.id" v-for="data in r" :key="data.id" :selected="item.r !== null && item.r.id === data.id">
{{ data.name }}
</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to achieve is pass the data.color from r instead of #000 from

```
v-bind:style="{ background: '#000' }
```

I just cannot work out how to pass such data outside the v-for loop.

Any idea how to do this please? Any tricks?

Thank you.

Comment: Your v-bind:style attribute is is missing a quote at the end.You could try v-bind:style="{ background: item.color }"

Comment: Thanks, this was a mistake from my side when I copied the code over. the item.color would be part of the tr loop, my problem is the data.color(the select loop). I need to get the data.color from the select loop to set a parent dom object above it, in this case the actual <select> tag.

Comment: If you mean you want the select's background to match whatever option you've selected it's quite easy. You just put a v-model="selectedThing" on your <select> and in your Vue component's data. Then change the :value in the option to :value="data". After that you can use :style="{ background: selectedThing.color }" on your <select>

Comment: thanks I managed to sort it out but at the end it was a lot more complicated as I have multiple dynamically generated dropdown menus at the same time. Some getting data form the db others getting data from javascript mixin.